# ¿Cómo llenar un ComboBox en JAVA (NetBeans) con 2 columnas de una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

En *MySQL* tengo una tabla llamada *producto* que va relacionada con otra a la cual llamo *categoría*. En mi tabla *producto* tengo la llave foránea `id_categoria`. Quisiera mostrar en el *ComboBox* los campos `id_categoria` y `nombre_categoria`, ya que quiero que se vea el nombre de la categoría que está seleccionando, pero debo guardar como tal el id de la categoría.

Comment: Tendrás que hacer un _ComboBox_ personalizado para que tenga más de una columna, o concatenar como `String` los dos resultados y mostrarlos como si solo fuera uno. Tienes montones de ejemplos de ComboBox personalizado en Internet.

Comment: Agrega el codigo que tengas hecho.

Comment: Creo que primero debes decirnos si estas usando awt, swing, javafx o web y poner el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

hacer lo que dices es muy común, tienes que montar el select html de tal manera que el label del "option" sea el nombre_categoria y el value sea el id_categoria, un ejemplo así sería :

```
<select>
  <option value="id_categoria_1">Nombre categoria 1</option>
  <option value="id_categoria_2">Nombre categoria 2</option>
  <option value="id_categoria_3">Nombre categoria 3</option>
</select>
```

Saludos